# Authenticate firebase with botkit-storage-firebase module

Tags: firebase, botkit

I'm using botkit and I'm trying to get storage working through firebase.

I'm using the botkit-storage-firebase module: https://github.com/howdyai/botkit-storage-firebase

However when I try to save anything (or get anything), I'm getting `Permission denied` from Firebase

```
controller.storage.users.save({ id: 'words', words: response.words });
```

I had to set the security rules of the database to:

```
{
 "rules": {
   ".read": true,
   ".write": true
 }
}
```

To be able to use it, however, leaving my database without security is obviously not what I want.

How can I authenticate with Firebase with the `botkit-storage-firebase` module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same issue working with Botkit and Firebase. It turns out [botkit-storage-firebase](https://github.com/howdyai/botkit-storage-firebase) is using Firebase 2.0 which is not compatible with the current version. I found a pull request that hasn't been merged yet and used that repo and everything works smoothly now. You can probably change your security rules back as well.

Here's the link to the fork- https://github.com/esjay/botkit-storage-firebase